# If a character is boring and predictable, is he one-dimensional, or two-dimensional?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

Let's suppose you have a character that's cliche, boring, and uninspired. Would you call the character one-dimensional, or two-dimensional?

Both uses seem to make sense to me. For example, if a character only has one primary motivation (he's a nerd, he's strong, he's dumb, he's evil), you might say his personality is one-dimensional (as in, he only has a single "aspect" to his character).

Likewise, you might describe him as two-dimensional, implying that he is a *flat* character (ie. the character lacks depth).

Which is the correct expression?

Comment: It's one less than the medium. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common term is one-dimensional.

I did a search on JSTOR, and virtually every single result (well, the first two pages, I got bored) for [*two-dimensional character*](http://www.jstor.org/action/doAdvancedSearch?f4=all&c1=AND&ed=&f0=all&c2=AND&acc=off&q0=%22two-dimensional+character%22&q5=&q2=&c3=AND&c5=AND&f2=all&f5=all&f3=all&q6=&c6=AND&f1=all&q4=&isbn=&sd=&pt=&c4=AND&la=&f6=all&q3=&q1=) was for either mathematics/physics/science articles or for articles on art pieces (in both cases, literal second dimensions).

Searching for [*one-dimensional character*](http://www.jstor.org/action/doAdvancedSearch?f4=all&c1=AND&ed=&f0=all&c2=AND&acc=off&q0=%22one-dimensional+character%22&q5=&q2=&c3=AND&c5=AND&f2=all&f5=all&f3=all&q6=&c6=AND&f1=all&q4=&isbn=&sd=&pt=&c4=AND&la=&f6=all&q3=&q1=) brought quite a number of literature articles into the fold (along with the literal references in math/art).

I'm a literature guy (thought I don't work in the English language), and I frankly, calling a character two- or three-dimensional just sounds odd.  I'd just call someone *one-dimensional* when they lack the qualities of a normal character, and perhaps say something about another character having *(more) depth*, that is, more dimensions.

Comment: JSTOR? Also, this seems like the most credible answer since you have sources, but can you link to your searches?

Comment: @MatthewNeuteboom JSTOR is a database of scholarly articles.  Unfortunately, access to it is not free and I don't know if searches are available to everyone since I'm automatically logged in on campus.  I've added a link to the searches, though. If you're on a university campus, you probably just click the link, or if you're affiliated with a university, there is probably a proxy login to use.

Answer (score 2):

A character without depth is "flat" and two-dimensional, as a piece of paper as opposed to a block of wood. "One-dimensional" could only be used to describe something that has a single defining characteristic. In my opinion, a character's *thinking* or motivation might be one-dimensional, but the character could only be called two-dimensional.

Comment: Yes, it's a metaphor problem.

Answer (score 0):

If he's boring because the writer has written about him in a boring way, he's one dimensional.

If he's boring because that's his actual personality, he's two-dimensional.